# python 3 os.stat not following symlink

Tags: python, symlink, stat

I am using Python 3.9.0, the latest available for Slackware. When using `os.stat` on a symlink, I keep getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. From reading the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.stat), `os.stat` should follow the symlinks by default.

```
import sys
path = r'/mnt/user/home/my.file'
print(os.stat(path))

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, a file in the same directory that is not a symlink works. I also tried:

`print(os.stat(path, follow_symlinks=True))`

That should be true by default but I tried it anyway and it didn't work.

I tried using `os.lstat` which worked but is not what I need, as it is for the link itself. I can't figure out why it is not following the symlink. I thought maybe a space in the directory might be a cause but as I mentioned, there is no issue with other files in the same directory that are not symlinks. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the symlink points to an existing file? That's the error you'd see if the symlink was pointing to a non-existent file.

Comment: Ah, of course. I feel silly now. I use hard links more often than soft links so that didn't cross my mind but that indeed was the case. Thanks.